# Does changing the Keystore value change the key password?

Tags: java, keytool

I've changed my Keystore password. I also want to change a key password  for an alias in the keystore. But I get this error when using `-keypasswd`

```
-keypasswd commands not supported if -storetype is PKCS12
```

By changing the keystore password have I also changed the key password? There is only one key in the keystore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Changing the keystore password doesn't change the key password automatically. You have to issue the respective change keystore password (`-storepasswd`) and change key password (`-keypasswd`) separately.

The internet standard for the PKCS12 keystore format is it has only 1 entry, and the keystore password is the same as the key password.

The way I've seen `keytool` work is, it doesn't need the `storetype` attribute when you change the keystore or key password. But when you supply the `storetype` attribute as `PKCS12` it actually complains if you supply the `keypass` attribute, saying that it will not honor it.

So to answer your question to change the key password, don't supply the `storetype` attribute. Your command should look like:

> keytool -keypasswd -keystore [p12Keystore] -storepass [oldPassword] -new [newPassword] -alias [entry]

Comment: [citation needed]